# Count the same order_id and output how many in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to count how many rows there is of the same order_id in the table `refnumbers`

So it should output:

```
There's 5 rows with the order_id 123

There's 9 rows with the order_id 124

There's 18 rows with the order_id 125

There's 2 rows with the order_id 77
```

It's the column `order_is` that it should counter after in the table `refnumbers`

I dont really know how to do this without specifically mention a order_id and then do a loop through them in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `group by` on the column that you want to get the count for.

**This does not work**

```
SELECT count(*) as rowcount
FROM refnumbers
```

Will give you a single row with all rowcounts

**Count per distinct order_id**

```
SELECT order_id, count(*) as rowcount
FROM refnumbers
GROUP BY order_id /*WITH ROLLUP*/
ORDER BY order_id
```

Will give you the count per distinct order_id.
If you want to get the total count as well uncomment the `with rollup` part.